# Weird error in typing latex eqn

Tags: equations

typing this:

```
\begin{equation} \label{u_cart}
 \begin{array}{ll}
  u(x,y)_{N=5}=
  \begin{cases}
    \begin{array}{ll}
 \frac{(x+i y)^5 \text{BesselJ}\left[\text{{``}1.5{''}} \sqrt{x^2+y^2},5\right]}{\left(x^2+y^2\right)^{5/2}} & 0<\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\frac{1}{2} \\
 \frac{(x+i y)^5 \left(\text{BesselJ}\left[3 \sqrt{x^2+y^2},5\right]+\text{BesselY}\left[3 \sqrt{x^2+y^2},5\right]\right)}{\left(x^2+y^2\right)^{5/2}}
& \frac{1}{2}<\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<1 \\
 \frac{(x+i y)^5 \text{HankelH1}\left[\sqrt{x^2+y^2},5\right]}{\left(x^2+y^2\right)^{5/2}} & \sqrt{x^2+y^2}>1 \endgroup
 \end{cases}
\end{array}
\end{array}
\end{equation}
```

I get 37 weird errors, although it seems to show nicely. What is wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: welcome to TeX.SE! You have mismatch in order of opening and closing environments. Also, all `array`s are superfluous. Use only of `cases` is sufficient.

Comment: After an error, "showing nicely" is a lucky outcome because TeX takes a guess at what you meant.

Answer (score 5):

You did not need the `array`s, because the first one operated on a single column, and the 2nd one was redundant to what `cases` provides (further, one of the `array`s was mismatched with `cases`).  You also had a stray `\endgroup` thrown in for no reason, which was excised.  I also added extra vertical space with `\\[8pt]`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\begin{document}   
\begin{equation} \label{u_cart}
  u(x,y)_{N=5}=
  \begin{cases}
 \frac{(x+i y)^5 \text{BesselJ}\left[\text{{``}1.5{''}} 
 \sqrt{x^2+y^2},5\right]}{\left(x^2+y^2\right)^{5/2}} 
 & 0<\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\frac{1}{2} \\[8pt]
%
 \frac{(x+i y)^5 \left(\text{BesselJ}\left[3 \sqrt{x^2+y^2},5\right]
 +\text{BesselY}\left[3 \sqrt{x^2+y^2},5\right]\right)}
 {\left(x^2+y^2\right)^{5/2}}
 & \frac{1}{2}<\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<1 \\[8pt]
%
 \frac{(x+i y)^5 \text{HankelH1}\left[\sqrt{x^2+y^2},5\right]}{\left(x^2+y^2\right)^{5/2}} & \sqrt{x^2+y^2}>1 
 \end{cases}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you for this!

Comment: @Atelier You're welcome.  If it fully answers your question and is the most suitable if multiple answers have been provided, feel free to click the check mark to the left of my answer.  That will tell other readers that you found an answer that is "most useful" for answering your question.  Once you get enough reputation (15 pt I think), you can click the up-arrow to the left of *any* question or answer (except your own), to indicate you found the question or answer "useful":

Answer (score 4):

Here's a variation on Steven Segletes's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/593951/5001). First, use a `dcases` environment (provided by the `mathtools` package, which is a superset of the `amsmath` package) to show the fractions in display style. Second, get rid of the `\left` and `\right` directives, as their sizing operations are good for the material at hand. Third, define `BesselJ`, `BesselY`, and `HankelH1` as math operators, to get the spacing right.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for 'dcases' environment
\DeclareMathOperator{\BesselJ}{BesselJ}
\DeclareMathOperator{\BesselY}{BesselY}
\DeclareMathOperator{\HankelH}{HankelH1}
\begin{document}   

\begin{equation} \label{u_cart}
u(x,y)^{}_{N=5}=
\begin{dcases}
 \frac{(x+i y)^5 \BesselJ[\textnormal{``1.5''} 
   \sqrt{x^2+y^2},5]}{(x^2+y^2)^{5/2}} 
   & 0<\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\frac{1}{2} \\[8pt]
%
 \frac{(x+i y)^5 \bigl(\BesselJ[3 \sqrt{x^2+y^2},5]
   +\BesselY[3 \sqrt{x^2+y^2},5]\bigr)}
   {(x^2+y^2)^{5/2}}
   & \frac{1}{2}<\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<1 \\[8pt]
%
 \frac{(x+i y)^5 \HankelH[\sqrt{x^2+y^2},5]}{(x^2+y^2)^{5/2}} 
   & \hphantom{\frac{1}{2}<{}}\sqrt{x^2+y^2}>1 
\end{dcases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks, very nice.