# Difficult equation to partition on several arrays

Tags: equations, arrays

with the given eqn, Mathematica thinks this is the best way to type it in TEX. But it goes way beyond the margins.

[image]

I was thinking of moving everything right to the curly bracket down one line, but it doesn't work.

Any ideas on how to put on two lines?

```
  \begin{equation}
-\frac{11 i (x+i y)^5 \text{BesselJ}\left[5,\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right]}{\left(x^2+y^2\right)^{5/2}}\\+\left(
\begin{array}{ll}
 \{ & 
\begin{array}{ll}
 e^{5 i \text{ArcTan}[x,y]} \text{BesselJ}\left[1.5 \sqrt{x^2+y^2},5\right] 
    & 0<\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\frac{1}{2} \\
 e^{5 i \text{ArcTan}[x,y]} \left(\text{BesselJ}\left[3 \sqrt{x^2+y^2},5\right]+\text{BesselY}\left[3 \sqrt{x^2+y^2},5\right]\right) 
    & \frac{1}{2}<\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<1 \\
 e^{5 i \text{ArcTan}[x,y]} \text{HankelH1}\left[\sqrt{x^2+y^2},5\right] 
    & \sqrt{x^2+y^2}>1 \\
 0  & \text{True}\right)
\end{array}
\end{array}
\end{equation}
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Welcome to the site.  You should provide a small compiling example, not just a code snippet.  Further, there are errors in the code you provide.

Comment: Edited. The errors you mentioned are corrected, but there is still an error missing \right. inserted and "you cant use eqnno in math mode"

Comment: Just out of idle curiosity: What's the meaning of `0  & \text{True}`?

Comment: @Mico That it exists, not a singularity there

Answer (score 2):

As with your [earlier query](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/593949/5001), I think you should consider replacing the nested `array`s with a single `dcases` environment. Since the full equation is too long to fit on a single line, consider using a `multlined` environment inside the `equation` environment. I would also get rid of all `\left` and `\right` sizing directives as they do absolutely nothing useful.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for 'dcases' and 'multlined' environments
\DeclareMathOperator{\BesselJ}{BesselJ}
\DeclareMathOperator{\BesselY}{BesselY}
\DeclareMathOperator{\HankelH}{HankelH1}
\DeclareMathOperator{\ArcTan}{ArcTan}
\begin{document}   

\begin{equation}
\begin{multlined}[t]
-\frac{11 i (x+i y)^5 \BesselJ[5,\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\,]}{(x^2+y^2)^{5/2}}\\
+ \begin{dcases}
 e^{5i \ArcTan[x,y]} \BesselJ[1.5 \sqrt{x^2+y^2},5] 
   & \text{if }0<\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\tfrac{1}{2} \\
 e^{5i \ArcTan[x,y]} (\BesselJ[3 \sqrt{x^2+y^2},5]+\BesselY[3 \sqrt{x^2+y^2},5]) 
   & \text{if }\tfrac{1}{2}<\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<1
\\
 e^{5i \ArcTan[x,y]} \HankelH[\sqrt{x^2+y^2},5] 
   & \text{if }\hphantom{\tfrac{1}{2}<{}}\sqrt{x^2+y^2}>1 \\
 0 
   & \text{True}\vphantom{\tfrac{1}{2}}
\end{dcases}
\end{multlined}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! This work great. Except for a "undefined control sequence"

Comment: @Atelier - Did you copy the four `\DeclareMathOperator` directives into your document?

Comment: good point! forgot that...